# Unintended blank space in legend after Cyrillic letters

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there any way to change the dimensions of the box of legend in ggplot2? There are too much of white space on my plot, which legend apparently requires (see borders of the box), but I don't need it.
Could it be because of the cyrillic alphabete? If I name legend as 'A','B','C' etc, it works normally as usual.
Here is my code:

```
require(ggsci)
# scale_fill_jco() & scale_color_jco()

gg_the <- ggplot(the_melt) + 
  geom_point(aes(RYear,Rank,color=the_melt$Университет),size=1.5) +
  geom_line(aes(RYear,Rank,color=the_melt$Университет,group=the_melt$Университет),size=1) +
  scale_y_reverse() + 
  scale_color_jco(name = 'Университет', labels = c('МГТУ им. Н.Э. Баумана','Московский государственный университет имени М.В. Ломоносова','(среднее значение по всем университетам)','Национальный исследовательский ядерный университет МИФИ','Национальный университет науки и технологии (МИСиС)','Новосибирский государственный университет','Санкт-Петербургский государственный университет')) +
  theme(legend.box.background = element_rect()) +
  labs(title ="Ранги", x = "Год", y = "Ранговый диапазон")
gg_the
```

It's what the plot looks like:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. please specify required packages. Where does `scale_color_jco` come from . And as @alanocallaghan already mentioned - please provide a reproducible example

Comment: I think this might indeed be a problem with the cyrillic characters. This older thread may help https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/vMHeI2ZmwAY

Comment: Thanks for your comment! scale_color_jco is from package ggsci, I edited my question.

Comment: and this one might help too. There are some links to questions contained https://github.com/andrewheiss/SublimeKnitr/issues/17

Comment: I don't see any extraneous space when reproducing this plot.

Comment: I have just explored that it may be due to the syslocal properties. Anyway I keep on my trials.

Comment: if you find a solution, feel free to post it as an answer. Also consider reducing your example to the suggested code as per my comment below

Comment: Have you found a solution? Funnily, when reproducing your plot today, I didn't have the problem. Maybe restart a completely new R session? I'll also rename your question in order to better fit your problem

Comment: No, I have not :( And I decided to cut the unneeded space in image editor.
How do I close the question?

Comment: Don't close it! It may at some point be answered. I will try to figure the thing out and if I don't find a solution, put a bounty on this question.

Comment: hmm, when trying to reproduce it with the code in the comment to below's answer, I do not get blank space any more. I think this may be indeed some problem with installed fonts, system you use, etc. As I cannot reproduce it and neither can @alanocallaghan I will cast a close vote. other members will have a look and decide if this needs to be closed. it will remain but won't be answerable for most members.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your plot as you have not supplied any example data. However, you can insert line breaks into the legend to reduce the horizontal space taken up without reducing the font size. For example (notice the `\n` line breaks):

```r
  scale_color_jco(
    name = 'Университет',
    labels = c('МГТУ им. Н.Э. Баумана',
      'Московский государственный\nуниверситет имени М.В. Ломоносова',
      '(среднее значение по\nвсем университетам)',
      'Национальный исследовательский\nядерный университет МИФИ',
      'Национальный университет \nнауки и технологии (МИСиС)',
      'Новосибирский государственный\nуниверситет',
      'Санкт-Петербургский\nгосударственный университет')) +
```

Comment: Though it doesn't solve my problem with empty space, it makes legend looks better. Thanks!

Comment: If you post some example data I'll see if I can figure out why the empty space appears

Comment: I cannot make example data to reproduce this problem, so could you take a look on the original data? https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DYLJoX7f4bbcgycyiUtTn7ZknlpEO9dB/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @EvgeniyCherniavskiy yes you almost always can. For example, you can boil your problem down to the use of simply the labels with cyrillic letters, using an inbuilt data frame: `ggplot(iris) + geom_point(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, color = Species))+ 
  scale_color_discrete(labels = c('МГТУ им. Н.Э. Баумана',
                                'Московский государственный университет имени М.В. Ломоносова',
                                '(среднее значение по всем университетам)'))`

Answer (score 0):

Try setting graphics device to “Cairo” at Tools–> Global Options...–>General–>Graphics–>Backend.

This was previously done by some coding (or via ggsave), but now the choice of graphics device for the Plot pane is implemented in RStudio, so it should be sufficient.